# why my database still showing 2147483647 error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, biginteger

I have problem with my database due to the `capacity` of the `variable`.
So, I changed my `id` from `integer` to `bigInteger` as show below. `id` will be storing barcode number.

```
class CreateItemsTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name',100);
        $table->decimal('buying_price', 5, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

However, when I try to access the item table from other controller, the page shows this error

> No query results for model [App\Item] 2147483647

This is how my `controller` looks like. I want to make my `item_id` for `order` `equal` to `item->id`.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'item_id'=>'required|integer',
        'quantity'=>'required|integer',
    ]);

    $item=Item::FindOrFail($request->item_id);

    $order=new Order;
    $order->status=$request->get('status');
    $order->item_id=$item->id;
    if ($request->get('status')=='Complete') {
        $item->quantity += $request->input('quantity');
    }
    $order->quantity=$request->input('quantity');

    $order->save();
    $item->save();

    return redirect('/Order')->with('success','Order added');
}
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your db schema, i do recommend using `$table->increments('id');` so you have a primary auto increment key. SQL unsigned int supports up to 4294967295.
Can you show the controller code, the error is telling you it cannot find Item with id 2147483647.

Comment: Change `$table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned()` To `$table->bigIncrements('id')`

Comment: Be aware that 2147483647 is actually **7FFFFFFF** when written in hexadecimal, which is the biggest possible 32-bits signed integer number. Most likely a magic value or an uninitialized ID in your query.

Comment: How are you trying to access the item table from the controller?

Comment: I have edit my question and put the controller in it.

Comment: Is `item_is` arriving to the controller correctly? If you're working with barcodes your data column should be a string because leading 0s matter in barcodes

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I am not sure the error coming from my laravel or my database. Because I already try to change the type of id from integer to bigInteger but it still saying that I cannot save the big number because it exceed the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFF,FFFF16) is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer in computing. It is therefore the maximum value for variables declared as integers (e.g., as int) in many programming languages.

You should change from **INTEGER** to **VARCHAR** in your **DB** to see if this fixes your error, if it does not, check your scripting language, there may be an operation that exceeds 2,147,483,647, therefore just showing its max.

Answer (score 1):

Did you rolled back your migrations and migrated again? If your table is already created, you have to create a new migration, changing  the wanted field

```
Schema::table('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned()->change();
});
```

and then migrate again with

```
php artisan migrate
```

**BUT THIS ISN'T THE BEST THING TO DO**

MySql has its methods of [handling auto increments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

You can create big increments in laravel with

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

[See documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns) for more information.

Comment: I have try both. bigInteger and bigIncrements. but the error is still there. My barcode is more than 2147483647.

Comment: Maybe if you don't need to make math operations with this barcode, you can store it as a text, and do the new migration with $table->text('id')->change(); and migrating

Comment: I have tried it. I can store the new item. But I just noticed that I can not even view it back. There are error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventory\resources\views\Item\show.blade.php)`

Comment: This error is telling you that the thing that you're trying to exctract 'name' doensn't exist. If it is a $item->name, then probably, this $item is null. Are you sure there is a record within your query parameters?

Comment: yes, I already check phpmyadmin. and the added item is already there.

Comment: What i said is that maybe in your laravel logic, you're not getting the actual database record. If i had some of your code and database records i could help, but i guess this is another problem by itself. Glad to hear that you was able to save the item with the barcode